# Why my javascript code work, but only once?

Tags: javascript, button, events, click, escaping

In my code, the rectangle should hide when I click on it and appear when I press Esc. Everything works only once. Why? And how can I solve this problem? Thank you for your attention.

```
const myBtn = document.querySelector('[data-btn]')


myBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   if (e.target === myBtn) {
      myBtn.classList.add('hide')

   }
})


document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
   if (e.code === "Escape") {
      myBtn.classList.add('show')
   }
})
```

Comment: You're adding classes but not removing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, when the button is clicked, it will add show class and esc will add hide class

But if you click then press esc, the button will have two classes: hide and show.

So this is a fix to your code: (sorry I coded this in my phone)

```
const myBtn = document.querySelector('[data-btn]')


myBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   if (e.target === myBtn) {
      myBtn.classList.add('hide')
      myBtn.classList.remove('show')
   }
})


document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
   if (e.code === "Escape") {
      myBtn.classList.add('show')
      myBtn.classList.remove('hide')
   }
})
```

If your class only have `display: none` in it, I suggest you to use `myBtn.style.display = 'none'`

Comment: Thank you. Now everything work correctly.

Comment: @KiraDresst no problem :). Can you consider marking this as answer so it can help people out?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to remove `hide` property when showing the button and `show` property when hiding it. The way your code is set up the button's `classList` looks like that

[] -> [hide] -> [hide, show] ...

but should look like

[] -> [hide] -> [show] ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the above methods but if it didnt work there is another method that uses `display` property which for hiding you use `display:none` and for showing you use `display:inline` with this the code will be like this :

```
const myBtn = document.querySelector('[data-btn]')


myBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    myBtn.style.display = "none";
})


document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
   if (e.code === "Escape") {
      myBtn.style.display = "inline";
   }
})
```

And `e.target == myBtn` can be deleted cause the event click is assigned for myBtn not for the entire document.
See more about `display` in this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.php)